# Expanding closet opening to its fullest

Tags: framing, closet, demolition

I have a closet in my kitchen that currently acts as our pantry. 
It looks like any standard closet with two sliding doors and shelves on the interior. 
It has a header above it for two sliding doors and the sides come in about 10 inches.

```
    _________________
    |               |
    |               |
    |__           __|  Top view 
     ^             ^
```

I am wondering if it is feasible to cut out the header and side walls (where the ^ is) in order to maximize the space it takes up.  Then insert a set of cabinets up top, a counter in the middle and then a set of drawers and cabinets beneath the counter.

The house is a colonial built in 1981 and I would verify this closet has no load bearing purpose before I did anything.  We are identifying ways to improve storage and use in our kitchen and I am hoping this would be a feasible option.

Is this crazy town to consider this? Or a common overhaul?  What sort of issues might I face in doing something like this?

Answer (score 2):

How easy this project is, will depend on the underlying framing.  There's two ways these corners could have been framed.

## Side walls to the end

This will make what you want to do fairly easy.

[image: Side walls to the end]
<sup>Top down view of the framing</sup>

## End walls to the side

This is the more likely of the two. Which means you'll either have to build out the corner, or lose 3 1/2" (+drywall thickness) in closet depth. Though I guess you're not really losing anything, from the interior dimensions of the original closet.

[image: End walls to the side]
<sup>Top down view of the framing</sup>

Aside from that. As long as the closet is not bearing, it shouldn't be too much work.

Comment: Good point, I do believe in my careful research (create holes in drywall and shine flashlight into) I saw the second example.  I also believe the entire frame has double 2X4's which is where the concern on load bearing exists.  Maybe that is standard, but we also have a wall interior to the closet that turns it into 2/3rds space and 1/3 space for brooms and this is constructed with 2 2x4's.  I cannot imagine the closet would/should be load bearing but I wont gamble to find out.

Answer (score -2):

If you **want** to do it then you **can** do it! For professional results a cabinet builder will be the right person to give you ideas and an estimate. For DIY you could measure the clear opening height, width, and depth you will be left with once you remove the header and front returns (side walls) and research pre-built options that will fit. I am not a huge fan of that Swedish furniture supplier (*kea), but they do have lots of pre-built cabinets and counters.

Comment: Arbitrarily removing door frames is usually OK; *headers* NOT so much.

Comment: @mazura, it's a kitchen closet/pantry built in 1981. The OP specifically said that it would be verified as non-load bearing prior to removal. OP states that the header is to support the sliding doors. Do you **really** think the header is load bearing? Seriously? If the header **was** load bearing, do you still think it is OK to "arbitrarily remove" the supporting door frames?

Comment: I didn't DV you but I think my comment is why it has been. I glossed over this whole page and missed that being said by the OP. As will other people who read this in the future. "If it's not load bearing, do w\e." would be better than "do w\e".